# Completely missing FSTAB

Tags: linux, filesystems, fedora

I recently found out that one of our servers has lost (probably someone deleted it) the /etc/fstab file, it's a Fedora Core 6.
Is there anything we can do to rebuild the fstab without a copy?

Comment: This may be considered [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If system is still running you can get a copy of fstab from file /proc/mounts.

Comment: Note that `/proc/mounts` is not an exact copy of `/etc/fstab` as it usually contains more entries and more detailed options.

Comment: @user2391 sadly /proc/mounts is empty, and now i can only access this machine in repair mode, it's a VPS, and the error i'm getting is:  /bin/cp: cannot create regular file `/etc/sysconfig/network.8175': Disk quota exceeded ERROR: Can't copy file /etc/sysconfig/network VE is unmounted VE start failed .

Comment: @doterobcn If system was shutdown after losing fstab you will likely have to manually mount root partition, create new fstab, than try and mount disk partitions form /dev and add entries to fstab. Alternatively you can read partition tables using fdisk. You can copy entries for tmpfs, procfs, sysfs, devpts from other fedora machine.